# Error to call Tinypass response in Restapi

Tags: php, api, curl

I am new in Tinypass api integration.

I try to integrate Tinypass API using PHP. Code below:

```
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://sandbox.tinypass.com/r2/access?rid=portfolio_id&user_ref=badashah26',
//    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                                'AID: xxxxxxxx', // PUT your AID
                                'signature: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // PUT your signature
                                'sandbox: true'
                                )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

print_r($resp); exit();
```

Response get but error display.

```
"error":{"message":"Access denied: invalid AID or signature","code":401}}
```

Any one can find solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Obviously you pass invalid custom header (AID or signature)

Comment: Then how to pass? Actually i pass correct. Display xxxxx instead of my original AID & signature.

Answer (score 0):

Our REST API documentation has been updated to provide a few steps on how to generate your own API header. Check out the documentation at http://developer.tinypass.com/main/restapi.

Best,
Tinypass Support

Answer (score 0):

Something like this..? (untested)

```
$aid = 'YOUR AID';
$action = '/r2/access?rid='.$rid.'&user_ref='.$userref;
$request = 'GET '.$action;
$url = 'http://sandbox.tinypass.com'.$action;
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256',$request,$aid);
$auth = $aid.':'.$signature;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: '.$auth);
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

print_r($resp); exit();
```